# fromWinHBITMAP is it avaialable in QT 5.1.1

Tags: c++, qt5.1

The documents state that the function isavailable however I get an error with the statement

```
img = QPixmap::fromWinHBITMAP(hRetVal).toImage();
```

The error is

```
error C3861: 'fromWinHBITMAP': identifier not found
```

I tried including

```
#include <QPixmap>
```

However I am still getting that . Any suggestions ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17461368/getting-a-hbitmap-from-a-qpixmap-in-qt5-windows

Answer (score 4):

It was moved into the QtWin namespace.

```
#include <QtWin>

HBITMAP bitmap = ...
QtWin::HBitmapFormat format = ...

QPixmap pixmap = QtWin::fromHBITMAP(bitmap, format);
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwin.html#fromHBITMAP

Comment: You may need to include it like this:  #include <QtWinExtras/QtWin>, and add: "winextras" to Qt at .pro file:   QT += core gui winextras